# Pdf of two uniform random variables with different ranges multiplied

Tags: probability, self-learning

We know that random variables that is of uniform distribution can only have 1 numerical value in a certain range and 0 otherwise.

But what happens if we multiply two uniformly distributed random variables? With two different ranges?

For example lets take $X$ ~ Uni($-1, 1$), $Y$ ~ Uni($0, 1$) and $U = XY$

From what I understood, we have:
$$
f_{XY}(xy) = f_{U}(u)
= \begin{cases}
1/2 & ; -1<X<1,& 0< Y<1 \\
0 & ; \,\text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$

How can this function have a pdf when it is known that basically $U$ is also a uniformly distributed random variable?

Comment: You may want to look [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) up.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are two independent, continuous random variables, described by probability density functions $f_{X}$ and $f_{Y}$ then the probability density function of $U=X Y$ is
$$
f_{U}(u)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X}(x) f_{Y}(u / x) \frac{1}{|x|}\mathrm d x .
$$
Now $X\sim$Unif$(-1,1)$, hence
$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}1/2&x\in(-1,1)\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}$$
and since $Y\sim$Unif$(0,1)$, hence
$$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}1&y\in(0,1)\\0&\text{else.}\end{cases}$$
Substitution yields your pdf.

Comment: But i dont know how to use the ranges in this formula, fx(x) is 1/2 in (-1,1) but what is the responsibility of this range in this formula? Do i just put 1/2 at fx(x) and 1 at fy(u/x)? Then what do i put at |x|? What does it represent in this formula? These questions are not documented at wikipedia page...

Comment: Say $u=3$. Then $f_Y(u/x)=1$ for $x\in(3,\infty)$. On the other hand, $f_X(x)=0$ for those $x$, so we have now deduced that $f_U(3)=0$. What about all other $u$?

Comment: for all u < 0, fu(u) = 0. As u/x becomes negative and fy is defined as 1 in range (0,1). for all u > 1/2, fu(u) = 0. As it would require y to be bigger than 1/2, or x to be bigger than 1. And for all u in (0,1/2) f(u) = 1/2...
I know the values in certain ranges, I dont know how to derive a pdf from this.

Comment: Careful, if $u=-\frac12$, for example, then $f_Y(u/x)=1$ for $x\in(-\infty,-\frac12)$. For those $x$, we have $f_X(x)=1$ if and only if $x\in(-1,-\frac12)$. Therefore, we have $$f(-\frac12)=\int_{-1}^{-\frac12}\frac1{2|x|}\mathrm dx=\frac12\log(2)\neq 0.$$

Comment: but isnt that integral equals to 1/2 * ln(x) from x=-1 to x=-1/2? How did you put negative values in ln?

Comment: Good question. Observe that the integral of $1/x$ equals $ln|x|$ with absolute values.